# False color image in Java from stack

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing, colorize

I have 3 greyscale images I want to colourise, I asked a similar question last week and took the advice there, I have the below code which reads the RGB values for each pixel in the image. I want to do this for each individual image i.e. 1st image read red pixel value, 2nd image read blue pixel value and 3rd image read green pixel value and create a new image from that.
I tried repeating the code 3 times but it just seemed to apply it to one pixel and keep repeating it but I couldnt find out why; I essentially copy and pasted the code 3 times but im sure theres a shorter and easier way, just not sure what!

Im reading the image using the following:

```
public static void main(final String args[])
    throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("src/resources/rgb.jpg");
    BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(file);
    BufferedImage image = toBufferedImage(src);
    save(image, "png");
}

private void img1(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage src) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {

            int clr = src.getRGB(x, y);
            int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            //int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            //int blue = clr & 0x000000ff; 

        }
    }
}
```

So I essentially need to repeat the code 3 times and then create a new image from the result. Just wondering if anyone could help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Pull your double for loop out into a method (not sure exactly how you want it to work):

```
private void doStuffToImage(Image image, Image src) {
  for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
      final int clr = src.getRGB(x, y);
      final int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
      final int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
      final int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, ditch all the `final`s.

Comment: By creating the method like you suggested above, do I define all the variables in the main method?

Comment: Nah, just keep them as local variables to this method unless you need them outside. Like I said i'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but something like this will reduce code duplication.

Comment: At the minute im essentially just trying to load in 3 buffered images, and get the variables for red, green and blue for each like in the code above. Ive edited my code in the original post, is this what you meant?